# How to delete a row from SQL using and image and a confirm box

Tags: html, sql, database

I have a HTML table with a redcross at the end of every row. I need this image to ask the user to confirm deleting the booking which is on that line and then remove it from the SQL database.

This is the code that is used for creating the HTML table:

```
while($row = sqlite_fetch_array($resultrooms))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['BookingID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Period'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['RoomID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><img src='/Tutorials/sandbox/myfiles/Pictures/redcross.png' alt='Cancel?' height='42' width='42' onclick='del()'></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
```

For example : The user clicks the redcross on row 2. I need to figure out a way to select the data on line two, place it into a confirm popup that says :

```
"Are you sure you want to cancel your booking on Date , Room, Period"
```

and then remove it from a SQL database.

Any suggestions? Or just even any ideas on how to select data from that specific HTML row.

Answer (score 0):

Use the BookingID as class for the tr. Now you can track a click (with javascript) on the img and get the class from your table row which is the ID. With the ID (which I suppose is unique) you can easily delete your data from the SQL Table.

Comment: While the ID is unique, there is not a specific booking I want gone. The user should be able to pick any of the red crosses and delete that specific row. Unless I am missing something, I dont think this will work :\

Comment: actually that might work. Any chance you could code what you mean as I am struggling to do it myself.